# Are some special chars(<>) in function names not supported by windbg/cdb?

Tags: binary-analysis, c++, windbg

I have a function in a binary like this `class<class1::class2>::function`. I can't directly use commands like `bp`, `u`, `x` on the function. The only option I have right now is `x class*` and then look in the output for the address and then set a breakpoint `bp <address>`.

Is there something that I'm missing? Its too cumbersome to copy and paste addresses each debugging session. One option is to use pykd, but I am looking for a pure windbg solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

they are supported if you add the special escape sequence **[`@!"  symbol "`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/breakpoint-syntax)**

make sure you set a resolved breakpoints not an unresolved one

and be aware a single address may point to several instantiations of these classes

```
windbg version 
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17744.1001 X86

lets look for some functions with angle brackets in them

0:000> x /f /v windbg!*<*<*<*

prv func   00b76da9            6d windbg!Debugger::Utils::SmartCleanup_______snipped
prv func   00b76e16            46 windbg!Debugger::Utils::SmartCleanup_______snipped
pub func   00b9bcd1             0 windbg!std::basic_string<char,std::_______snipped
snip 



0:000> bp @!" windbg!Debugger::Utils::SmartCleanup_____snipped "
Bp expression '@!" windbg!Debugger::Utils::SmartCleanup<<lamb___snipped "'    

could not be resolved, adding deferred bp <<<<<

0:000> bl
     0 e Disable Clear u             0001 (0001) (@!" windbg!Debugger::Utils::SmartCleanup<<lambda_snipped
```

Answer (score 2):

`bm` might help to match your function by some pattern. See [this post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/13359/22324).